# List unique values from splunk events

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation

`index=myIndex container_name="abc-mno-pqr" "status code :: 50*"`

For this splunk query I am getting events like below

`[123-456-789-098] | 2023-07-26 12:05:31:245 [application-1] INFO com.example.event.SampleClasss - status code :: 500`

`[321-564-986-197] | 2023-07-26 13:04:38:287 [application-1] INFO com.example.event.SampleClasss - status code :: 503`

`[655-256-278-865] | 2023-07-26 13:05:42:245 [application-1] INFO com.example.event.SampleClasss - status code :: 503`

`[457-234-856-528] | 2023-07-26 14:08:23:123[application-1] INFO com.example.event.SampleClasss - status code :: 504`

`[457-234-856-528] | 2023-07-26 14:08:24:123[application-1] INFO com.example.event.SampleClasss - status code :: 504`

In the above events last one is duplicate transactionId but displayed because there is difference in the timestamp i.e 1 second

I need to display unique Ids with corresponding status codes like below.

| transactioId | Status-Code |
| --- | --- |
| 123-456-789-098 | 500 |
| 321-564-986-197 | 503 |
| 655-256-278-865 | 503 |
| 457-234-856-528 | 504 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`stats`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/stats) will be your friend here:

```
index=myIndex container_name="abc-mno-pqr" "status code :: 50*"
| stats latest(status) as Status-Code by transactionId
```

If the fields `transactionId` and `status` are not yet extracted, you'll need to pull them out

A way to do this at search time is with [`rex`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/rex):

```
| rex field=_raw "code\D+(?<status>\d+)"
| rex field=_raw "^\[(?<transactionId>[^\]]+)"
```

regex101 verifications: https://regex101.com/r/JDgzya/1 && https://regex101.com/r/O5qTJ9/1

---

If you want to see *all* statuses for each transactionId, do this instead:

```
index=myIndex container_name="abc-mno-pqr" "status code :: 50*"
| stats count by transactionId status
| rename status as Status-Code
```

and with timestamps:

```
index=myIndex container_name="abc-mno-pqr" "status code :: 50*"
| stats count by transactionId status _time
| rename status as Status-Code
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `stats` is an aggregating command.  While it's a good solution in this case, it may not be appropriate in all scenarios.  OTOH, `dedup` removes duplicates without aggregation or transformation and is not that inefficient.

Comment: @RichG - `dedup` is *incredibly* inefficient in the overwhelming majority of cases (ie >96% of the time). Using `dedup` *after* `stats` or some other function *can* make sense ... but it is almost never the "right" answer :)

Comment: @warren I created query as like this `index=myIndex container_name="abc-mno-pqr" "status code :: 50*" | rex field=_raw "code\D+(?<status>\d+)" | rex field=_raw "^\[(?<transactionId>[^\]]+)" | stats latest(status) as Status-Code by transactionId` but it is giving value of status as `5` only not complete code like `503` or `504`

Comment: @Sat - is it the *count* that is `5`, or the *status* that is `5`?

Comment: @warren It's not `count`, `status` is giving `5` instead of `503` or `504`

Comment: @Sat - are you sure your events only look like what you initially shared?

Comment: Yes @warren events look like what I shared initially in the question. From your answere splunk query I am getting data in table format with transactioIDs and StatusCodes but the problem is StatusCodes are not getting printed completely. I mean for `501` or `503` or `500` statuses getting only `5`

Comment: @Sat - per the regex, and your initial search of `"status code :: 50*"`, the newly-created `status` field is going have at least two digits. Unless there is *another* sequence of `code<one-or-more-nondigit-characters><some-digits>` that is being seen prior to the sequence `status code :: 50<possible-more-digits>`. You can try extending the regex from `"code\D+(?<status>\d+)"` to `"status code\D+(?<status>\d+)"`

Answer (score 0):

The assertion "displayed because there is difference in the timestamp i.e 1 second" is incorrect.  The events are displayed because they were sent to Splunk and nothing in the query removes them.

To see only unique events, use the `dedup` command to remove duplicates.

```
index=myIndex container_name="abc-mno-pqr" "status code :: 50*"
| dedup transactionId
```

This assumes the transactionId field is extracted automatically.

Comment: `dedup` is somewhat unpredictable (and inefficient) - it should *almost* always be avoided (especially early in a search)